# TK (LTK) Paint Program (Raster)

Tags: graphics, common-lisp, tk-toolkit, ltk

I really want to make a raster paint program while keeping the pixel model CPU side.
I want to expose the underlying data structure to users of the program so they can extend it with their own functionality. (Think how Emacs provides a few primitives yet users extend the program indefinitely with Emacs Lisp)

Now, from what I can tell Tk (and LTK by extension) mostly favors a Canvas which deals with pinning premade objects to it acting as a growing queue. My need is going to be having functionality of simply editing smallish bitmaps. Is it even feasible to build a program as simple as Microsoft Paint in Tk? ***Keep in mind, I do NOT want vector shapes-I want a real time raster editor.*** The whole model of editing raster objects in real time seems to fight the way computer graphics are done today and I'm simply trying to find a system that allows me to edit an array of "pixels" and display them with sufficient "human speed".

I'm not bound to Ltk but it's one of the most complete toolkits we have in Common Lisp it can also send messages directly to Tk so we get new features as they roll out. I'm just kind of fighting a modern graphics model to maintain a clean API for users' scripting.

Comment: Perhaps this helps «http://www.posoft.de» (quoted in «https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Bitmap+Editor»)